# How to prevent VMWare Workstation 15 to suspend running VMs automatically when the host is shut down?

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

VMWare Workstation 15 on Windows 10 will suspend running VMs when the host is shut down.
Previous versions have option to choose what to do when the host is shut down e.g. suspend the VM/power off the VM, but the new version doesn't have this option anymore. (Note: there is an option that sounds like this, but doesn't work like this at all)

The bad thing about unintentional suspending of the VM is writing all RAM content to disk, which is not fast and uses up SSD TBW.

The goal is to let VMWare Workstaion 15 power of running VMs when the host is shut down. It will be better if it just prevent the host to shutdown if there is running VMs.

VMPlayer can't be used instead (lack of features)

Comment: What version exactly do you have installed?  VMWare Workstation 15 spans multiple versions (15.0, 15.1, 15.7) understanding which version you are using is important information.

Comment: @Ramhound 15.5.0

Comment: Have you considered writing a [PowerCLI](https://isjw.uk/shutting-down-a-virtual-machine-using-powercli/#:~:text=VMware%20PowerCLI%20allows%20us%20to%20shutdown%20a%20guest,before%20continuing%2C%20this%20can%20be%20done%20as%20follows.) script that is ran when the host machine is shutdown?

Comment: [Here](https://scriptigator.com/2020/11/22/how-to-restart-reset-shutdown-poweroff-vms-with-powercli/) is another variation of the script.  I would like to point out that you will be writing data to your SSD no matter if you suspend the VM or shutdown VM since there will be pending changes to the virtual hdd.